# rsync verbose print folders with strange characters

Tags: bash, rsync

Using `rsync -avh` the list of folders stops printing when getting to a directory `ls` calls `''$'\302\220''í“¬ƒTƒ“ƒvƒ‹'` (badly encoded Japanese text that doesn't appear to be EUC-JP, ISO-2022-JP, or SHIFT_JIS). However it seems like rsync continues transferring, just not displaying. How can I get rsync to continue printing information?

More info: the locale is `en_US.UTF-8`, the source partition is ext4 and destination partition is NTFS (mounted with `mount`, probably `mount.ntfs`), though this seems to be a display issue rather than an actual transfer issue.

Comment: please mention what is your locale, what is the partition type (where this specific folder lies) and how it is mounted? Further it is not clear to me if the issue is only with `rsync` or even `ls` also gives this bad output!

Comment: You can try `reset` on the terminal and try again!

Comment: @user5325 I've added more info. Note that `ls` still displays the filename but rsync refuses to display any further information until I Ctrl-C.